# Can't read larger than 1kb in java

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files, large-files, bigdata

I have a question about dealing with large file in java.

I work on Eclipse neon, on Mac Pro. and I want to read .txt files in Java, the files size is in MB or GM.
I search on google and I have read all the question here in stackoverflow, and I try the the ways to reading the files. 
I tried the 
`FileReader and BufferedReader , also I tried FileInputStream`
when I read file equal or less than 100 KB, eclipse is ok and it read all the file. 
But if the file in MG or more than 100 KB,eclipse hanging and I must restart it.
I don't know what is the problem, Is it in my device or what? 
I really get confused of that, because all the ways I tried say it can read file with 1MG in some second. And with me it doesn't. 
Is there any API or anything that I can use it, to guarantee read whole file.
Please, any one have same problem, give me an advice.

This is the code:

```
 FileReader fileReader1 =  new FileReader("/Users/Desktop/i/36.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);
          String line ;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                token+=line+" ";
            }
System.out.println(token);
```

also I tried this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            for (String line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Comment: You have to post *the actual code*. Sounds like you have a loop that is stuck somewhere.

Comment: The problem is in your code. But you didn't post it, so... Also, more than 100KB is hardly bigdata. The tag "tinydata" would be more appropriate :-)

Comment: Have you tried that on normal command prompt/Terminal to see if it's run smmotly ?

Comment: @chrylis I added the code

Comment: @JBNizet I added the code

Comment: You're creating an insanely long line of text, without any line break. Eclipse won't be able to print that. Just print "OK, done" when you're done. Also, use a StringBuilder. Your code is very inefficient due to the insane amount of STring objects it needs to create and GC.

Comment: @Milan Can you please, explain more what do you mean?

Comment: Reading your code, it appears that 'token' is an in memory variable that becomes larger as the file is being read. Check that your Mac Pro is not running out of RAM.

Comment: ^^ You're reading the whole file in memory. That won't cause any problems for MB-sized files, but you will get out of memory for GB-sized files.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to print all the lines to make sure that eclipse read them, in my actual code I wanna do a process on them after I guarantee that it read it all of them. And how can I know that my mac pro out of memory?

Comment: @Wayno  how can I know that my mac pro out of memory?

Comment: Googling "Show Ram usage Mac Pro" gives me this link: http://www.macinstruct.com/node/423. You should be able to watch the RAM increase as the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

The first is slurping the whole file into a single variable (never use string concatenation in a loop; use a `StringBuilder`) and probably crushing your machine under GC load.

The second one *should* work, but it might take a while on a larger file; I'm surprised there's not a stream version of it. Run in the debugger and find if there's a line that's taking forever.

Comment: Thanks chrylis, I tried the StringBuilder, it print all the lines then it hide it,   please, what do you mean by GC load? and line taking forever?

Comment: @Geek "Then it hide it"? If you're going to be working in Java, you *have* to read up on the basics of how garbage collection works.

Comment: Yeah I know it, but I mean what can I do with it?